# How to remove add-in (?) from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vsto

Everytime I open a worksheet, I get this dialog box:

[image: Error message]

I don't really know what it is that is going on here (what is being installed).

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are NOT general software tech support.

Comment: Yeah, I just flagged my post so that it gets moved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inactivate an Excel add-in

```
Click the File tab, click Options, and then click the Add-Ins category.
In the Manage box, click Excel Add-ins, and then click Go.
In the Add-Ins available box, clear the check box next to the add-in that you want to inactivate, and then click OK.
```

In many cases, when you inactivate an add-in, it is removed from its group on the ribbon. In other cases, to remove the add-in from the ribbon, you may need to restart Excel.

Note    Inactivating an add-in does not remove the add-in from your computer. To remove the add-in from your computer, you must uninstall it.

To remove an Excel add-in

Important    If you originally installed the Excel add-in from a network file server or from a shared folder, you might need to remove the add-in from that location. If you installed the Excel add-in from a CD-ROM and you mapped your CD-ROM drive to a new drive letter after installing the add-in, you need to reinstall the add-in from the CD-ROM. If you are running any Excel add-ins from the CD-ROM, you must uninstall the Excel add-ins, and then reinstall them from the CD-ROM.

```
Exit Excel (click the File tab, and then click Exit).
In Windows Vista, click the Start button Button image, click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Programs and Features.
```

In Microsoft Windows XP, click the click the Start button, click Control Panel, and then double-click Add/Remove Programs.

```
Do one of the following:
    If you installed Excel as part of Microsoft Office, click Microsoft Office in the list of installed programs, and then click the Change button.
    If you installed Excel individually, click the name of your program in the list of installed programs, and then click the Change button.
    If you installed the add-in from the Download Center at Office.com, click the name of your program in the list of installed programs, and then click the Uninstall button.
Follow the instructions in the installation program.
```

Go to this link for more details http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/add-or-remove-add-ins-HP010342658.aspx#BMexceladdin